# How can I detect subgraph isomorphism on multigraph using Boost's vf2_subgraph_iso?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph, isomorphism

I'm trying to use Boost's [`vf2_subgraph_iso()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/graph/doc/vf2_sub_graph_iso.html) to detect subgraph isomorphism.

I can successfully do this on simple graph, but can not on [multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) (a graph which is permitted to have multiple edges).

Consider detecting subgraph isomorphism between following G1 and G2:

[image: graphs]

G1 is a subgraph of G2, and I want to detect that using following code:

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>

int main()
{
  // Define edge property
  typedef boost::property<
    boost::edge_name_t,
    char
  > edge_property;

  // Define graph type
  typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,           // OutEdgeListS
    boost::vecS,           // VertexListS
    boost::bidirectionalS, // DirectedS
    boost::no_property,    // VertexProperties
    edge_property,         // EdgeProperties
    boost::no_property,    // GraphProperties
    boost::listS           // EdgeListS
  > MyGraphType;

  // Build graph G1
  MyGraphType g1;
  std::vector<MyGraphType::vertex_descriptor> v1(3);
  for (auto itr = v1.begin(); itr != v1.end(); ++itr) {
    *itr = boost::add_vertex(g1);
  }
  boost::add_edge(v1[0], v1[1], edge_property('a'), g1);
  boost::add_edge(v1[0], v1[2], edge_property('a'), g1);
  boost::add_edge(v1[1], v1[2], edge_property('b'), g1);

  // Build graph G2
  MyGraphType g2;
  std::vector<MyGraphType::vertex_descriptor> v2(3);
  for (auto itr = v2.begin(); itr != v2.end(); ++itr) {
    *itr = boost::add_vertex(g2);
  }
  boost::add_edge(v2[0], v2[1], edge_property('a'), g2);
  boost::add_edge(v2[0], v2[2], edge_property('a'), g2);
  boost::add_edge(v2[1], v2[2], edge_property('a'), g2);
  boost::add_edge(v2[1], v2[2], edge_property('b'), g2);

  // Create predicate of edge
  typedef boost::property_map<MyGraphType, boost::edge_name_t>::type edge_name_map_t;
  typedef boost::property_map_equivalent<edge_name_map_t, edge_name_map_t> edge_comp_t;
  edge_comp_t edge_comp = boost::make_property_map_equivalent(
    boost::get(boost::edge_name, g1), boost::get(boost::edge_name, g2));

  // Create callback
  boost::vf2_print_callback<MyGraphType, MyGraphType> callback(g1, g2);

  // Execute
  const bool result = boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(
    g1, g2, callback, boost::vertex_order_by_mult(g1),
    boost::edges_equivalent(edge_comp));

  std::cout << "subgraph isomorphic? " << std::boolalpha << result << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Expected result:

```
(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2)
subgraph isomorphic? true
```

Actual result:

```
subgraph isomorphic? false
```

Where is my code wrong?

Sorry for my poor English. Thanks!

Comment: code reviewed [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8a304f069a8c4e3) and also creates the dot graphs https://imgur.com/a/sF95EoL

Answer (score 0):

The vf2_subgraph_iso will compare the properties of edge. In your codes, the property of edge 1->2 is 'b' in graph1, but it's 'a','b' in graph2. So they're not the same structure.

If you wanna it return true when matching only parts of all properties, you can use a struct and overload operator "==" by your rules.
For your example, the following codes will be fine.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>

int main()
{
  // Define edge property
  struct  EdgeProperties {
      EdgeProperties() {}
      EdgeProperties(char elabel) { _elabels.emplace_back(elabel);}
      EdgeProperties(std::vector<char>& elabels) :_elabels(elabels) {}
      /* overload == */
      bool operator==(EdgeProperties const& other) const {
        for (auto& my_l:_elabels) {
          for (auto& o_l:other._elabels) {
            if (my_l == o_l) return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      std::vector<char> _elabels;
  };

  typedef boost::property<
    boost::edge_name_t,
    EdgeProperties
  > edge_property;

  // Define graph type
  typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,           // OutEdgeListS
    boost::vecS,           // VertexListS
    boost::bidirectionalS, // DirectedS
    boost::no_property,    // VertexProperties
    edge_property,         // EdgeProperties
    boost::no_property,    // GraphProperties
    boost::listS           // EdgeListS
  > MyGraphType;

  // Build graph G1
  MyGraphType g1;
  std::vector<MyGraphType::vertex_descriptor> v1(3);
  for (auto itr = v1.begin(); itr != v1.end(); ++itr) {
    *itr = boost::add_vertex(g1);
  }
  boost::add_edge(v1[0], v1[1], edge_property('a'), g1);
  boost::add_edge(v1[0], v1[2], edge_property('a'), g1);
  boost::add_edge(v1[1], v1[2], edge_property('b'), g1);

  // Build graph G2
  MyGraphType g2;
  std::vector<MyGraphType::vertex_descriptor> v2(3);
  for (auto itr = v2.begin(); itr != v2.end(); ++itr) {
    *itr = boost::add_vertex(g2);
  }
  boost::add_edge(v2[0], v2[1], edge_property('a'), g2);
  boost::add_edge(v2[0], v2[2], edge_property('a'), g2);
  std::vector<char> tmp;
  tmp.emplace_back('a');
  tmp.emplace_back('b');
  boost::add_edge(v2[1], v2[2], edge_property(tmp), g2);

  // Create predicate of edge
  typedef boost::property_map<MyGraphType, boost::edge_name_t>::type edge_name_map_t;
  typedef boost::property_map_equivalent<edge_name_map_t, edge_name_map_t> edge_comp_t;
  edge_comp_t edge_comp = boost::make_property_map_equivalent(
    boost::get(boost::edge_name, g1), boost::get(boost::edge_name, g2));

  // Create callback
  boost::vf2_print_callback<MyGraphType, MyGraphType> callback(g1, g2);

  // Execute
  const bool result = boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(
    g1, g2, callback, boost::vertex_order_by_mult(g1),
    boost::edges_equivalent(edge_comp));

  std::cout << "subgraph isomorphic? " << std::boolalpha << result << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```